# Calling CloudFunction parameters from Flutter Web gives an error

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, flutter-web

I call the function like this from Flutter Web:

```
//* Call createUserDocuments
final _params = <String, dynamic>{
      param1: 'param1',
      param2: 1234,

};

final response = await CloudFunctions.instance
  .getHttpsCallable(functionName:'function1')
   .call(_params).timeout(Duration(seconds: 30));
```

But I always get this error in the Firebase console:

```
error: syntax error at or near "{"
```

Another message in the console says `INTERNAL`

The Cloud Function

```
exports.function1 = functions
.runWith({ memory: "256MB", timeoutSeconds: 10 })
.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

const param1 = data['param1']; 
const param2 = data['param2'];
const date = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();

console.log(`Got called: ${param1} ${param2} ${date.toMillis}`);

});
```

And moreover, if I call a function that doesn't require any parameters, it works.

My Flutter Doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.23.0-18.1.pre, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 x86_64, locale en-US)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Is there anymore information I need to add here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. So in the Cloud Function code I added a `.toMillis` To one of the params because it is a Timestamp object.

But the correct syntax supposed to be `.toMillis()`. Otherwise I would be just passing the function rather than invoking the function.

So guys please always remember to add that brackets. ;-)

*More notes: previously I said that the cloud function was working when I called from Flutter App. Sorry my mistake because I completely forgotten about adding the `.toMillis` function call in it. I have fixed the question to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

```
final _params = <String, dynamic>{
      param1: 'param1',
      param2: 1234,
};
```

The keys should be String here. So it should be like-

```
final _params = <String, dynamic>{
      'param1': 'param1',
      'param2': 1234,
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Quite a good observation. But actually those keys are String constants. And I have found the issue which J totally forgotten about. I have updated the question